# How do I change the way JS Beautify formats objects?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, js-beautify

I like JS Beautify for the most part but I really hate the default rules for how objects are formatted.

For example, this is how JS Beautify currently formats objects:

```
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(12.9716, 77.5946),
    scrollwheel: false,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
    }
};
```

Is there a way to ask JS Beautify to align all the `:` in the object like this:

```
var mapOptions = {
    zoom                 : 12,
    center               : new google.maps.LatLng(12.9716, 77.5946),
    scrollwheel          : false,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
    }
};
```

I use Visual Studio Code with [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lonefy.vscode-JS-CSS-HTML-formatter) to format my JavaScript.

Comment: I don't believe so.

Comment: I think that all you can do is format manually when you code and then wrap `/* beautify preserve:start */` and `/* beautify preserve:end */` around it so that [jsbeautify](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) leaves it alone.

Comment: @Xotic750 I doubt that I can maintain a large JavaScript project that way. Are there other formatters that are a little more flexible?

Comment: I've tried several but none of them have had the option that you are looking for. Maybe someone else has found one.

Comment: @Xotic750 Can you please name the others? Might be worth checking out.

Comment: A couple I have tried are: ESlint and  JSCS

Comment: See https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify/issues/365